# How to Convert DataTable to ListView Adapter in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, xamarin.android, android-listview

How can convert or use `DataTable` for `Listview` in `Xamarin.Android` like I
showed in my picture please help me...

Note that I use `Xamarin.Android` not `Xamarin.Forms`

[image: image here]

here is my code :

```
 namespace CRM.PL
            {
                [Activity(Label = "AC_Expense_Search")]
                public class AC_Expense_Search : Activity
                {
                    ListView listView1;


                protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.L_Expense_Search);
                    // Create your application here
                    //**********************************************
                    listView1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
                    //**************** Load Data ****************************
                    LoadData();
                    //**************** Event ****************************

                }

                public DataTable DataTableCollection { get; set; }

                void LoadData()
                {
  
                    DataTable dt = cls_Epense.Expense_select_Top10();
                    DataTableCollection = dt;
     
                    listView1.Adapter = dt;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant code directly in the body of the question, not just a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set `DataTable` for **ListView.Adapter** directly.

1. You need to get each item data from `DataTable` first,
2. Then you can add them for each `ListItem`s of `ListView`.
3. Last, you can set the `ListItem`s as data for ListView Adapter.

For example:

```
void LoadData()
{

    DataTable dt = cls_Epense.Expense_select_Top10();
    DataTableCollection = dt;

    List<ListItem> listItems = new List<ListItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ListItem  listitem = new ListItem();
        listitem.FirstParamater = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        listitem.SecondParamater = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        listitem.ThirdParamater = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        ...
        listItems.Add(listitem);
    }

    listviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, listItems );

    listView1.Adapter = listviewAdapter;
}
```

The sample code of **ListItem**, you need to custom the needed `ListItem` for your project.

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string FirstParamater { get; set; }
    public string SecondParamater { get; set; }
    public string ThirdParamater { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not worked!
when i'm run the application it give me this error :
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

and here is my code :

```
void LoadData()
        {
          
            DataTable dt = cls_Epense.Expense_select_Top10();
           

            List<Expense_Search> listItems = new List<Expense_Search>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                listItems[i].FirstParamater = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                listItems[i].SecondParamater = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                listItems[i].ThirdParamater = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
              
            }

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Expense_Search>(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, listItems);

            listView1.Adapter = adapter;

        }



 public class Expense_Search
    {
        public string FirstParamater { get; set; }
        public string SecondParamater { get; set; }
        public string ThirdParamater { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I set the data for `List<ListItem>` directly. You need to new `ListItem` and set value for it, then can add `ListItem` for `List<ListItem>`. I have updated the answer, you can have a try again.